# add((RelativeLayout) findViewById) to ArrayList<RelativeLayout>

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dynamic

I have the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public ArrayList<RelativeLayout> buttons = new ArrayList<RelativeLayout>();
    public ArrayList<Integer> drawableId = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Rlayout);
        scrool = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrool);
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
            {
                String buttonID = "Llayout" + i;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id",
                        getPackageName());
                //The problem is here
                buttons.get(i).add((RelativeLayout) findViewById(resID));

                buttons.get(i).setOnClickListener(this);
                drawableId.add(getResources().getIdentifier("supa" + i, "drawable", getPackageName()));
            }
        }
    }


  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
            if (buttons.get(i).getId() == v.getId()) {
                index = i;
                Intent trimite = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RecipeView.class);
                Bundle colet = new Bundle();
                colet.putString("key", Content.RETETE[i]);
                colet.putInt("keyimg", drawableId.get(i));
                trimite.putExtras(colet);
                startActivity(trimite);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot get this to work:

```
buttons.get(i).add((RelativeLayout) findViewById(resID));
```

Java error says that: `add((RelativeLayout) is undefined for the type RelativeLayout`.

The add method works for ArrayList drawableId, one line below but not for buttons. Can someone, please, help me?

Here is my xml layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:id="@+id/scrool"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:fillViewport="true"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"
       tools:context=".MainActivity"
       tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/Rlayout"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:keepScreenOn="true"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

           <RelativeLayout
               android:id="@+id/Llayout0"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:clickable="true"
               android:focusable="true"
               android:onClick="onClick"
               android:orientation="vertical" >

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/iv0"
                   android:layout_width="50dp"
                   android:layout_height="50dp"
                   android:layout_gravity="left"
                   android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                   android:src="@drawable/supa0" />

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/tv0"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                   android:text="@string/supa"
                   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
           </RelativeLayout>

           <RelativeLayout
               android:id="@+id/Llayout1"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:clickable="true"
               android:focusable="true"
               android:onClick="onClick"
               android:orientation="vertical" >

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/iv1"
                   android:layout_width="50dp"
                   android:layout_height="50dp"
                   android:layout_gravity="left"
                   android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                   android:src="@drawable/supa0" />

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/tv1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                   android:text="@string/supa1"
                   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
           </RelativeLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

I made buttons from RelativeLayouts. Each RelativeLayout button has text and an icon next to the text.  All of the RelativeLayouts buttons are in a LinearLayout so that they align under each other.

When the RelativeLayouts buttons and the ArrayList drawableId were simple arrays it worked great but I don't want to modify the array every time I add a new RelativeLayout button.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<RelativeLayout> buttons = new ArrayList<RelativeLayout>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> drawableId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private LinearLayout linear;
    private ScrollView scrool;
    private int index;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Rlayout);
        scrool = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrool);


        for (int i = 0; i < linear.getChildCount(); i++) {
            {
                String buttonID = "Llayout" + i;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id",getPackageName());
                buttons.add((RelativeLayout)findViewById(resID));
                buttons.get(i).setOnClickListener(this);
                drawableId.add(getResources().getIdentifier("supa" + i, "drawable", getPackageName()));
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
            if (buttons.get(i).getId() == v.getId()) {
                index = i;
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,String.valueOf(index),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent trimite = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RecipeView.class);
                Bundle colet = new Bundle();
                colet.putString("key", Content.RETETE[i]);
                colet.putInt("keyimg", drawableId.get(i));
                trimite.putExtras(colet);
                startActivity(trimite);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please approve so it may help others.

Comment: I have another question. In Content class i have a string named RETETE , where i have some recipies stored. I then get them by the index id of the button with the recipie title.  I want to know what other methods can i use to store this recipies and have them already formated (like indents, bold, font, etc). So when i get them they are already formated. In a string i cant really format the text.

Answer (score 1):

The [`RelativeLayout` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) has no `add()` method.

`buttons` is an ArrayList of RelativeLayouts. When you call `buttons.get(i)`, you get a single RelativeLayout object. Since RelativeLayout has no `add()` method, you get this error.

It isn't entirely clear what your intent is with this code, but I am assuming that you are trying to add each of your RelativeLayouts to the `buttons` list.

If this is correct, you just need to remove the `get(i)` call, making that line into

```
buttons.add((RelativeLayout) findViewById(resID));
```

Comment: Like i said, every RelativeLayout is a button.                                  I am      I'm trying to add the Relative Layout buton to the list so that each button has an id from i to buttons.size().  Your method does not give any button an id so i can't click on any button.

Comment: I've added the onClick method from the same class.

Comment: I just want to add the id's fo the relative layouts for each button like i've done a line below with the buttons.get(i).setOnClickListener.

Comment: yes they do and using your method the error goes away. i run the program and i cant click on any button. that's my i tryed to used get(i).add.